# PHP changing image src on click of an upload button:

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, upload

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I figure if it is, SO will know. Basically I use a ajax-upload script to upload an image, and below the upload button I display a thumbnail of the current image.

Its for a shops products, so a product has numerous pictures, on load of the 'edit product' page, all the thumbnails are those that have already been saved to the DB. However when a user clicks the upload button and chooses a different file I would like the new image to be displayed instead, but the problem is, it hasn't been inserted into the DB yet.

Code looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">Product Thumbnail:</td>
    <td>
     <table>
        <tr>
         <td>
           <div id="upload" >
              <button type="button">Upload</button>
           </div>
         </td>
         <td id="myfilename"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="right">Thumb:</td>
    <td align="left">
    <img src="../shop/<?php echo $prodinforow["ProdThumb"]; ?>" width="115" border="0">&nbsp;<a href=""><img src="images/1001-cancel16.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" border="0"></a>
    <div id="upload"></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

So as you can see the img src gets echo'd from the DB in a simple query that is futher up the actual page, this works fine. I know that the filename of the uploaded image gets saved into a hidden form input called 'attachments' when the file is uploaded. But before the form is submitted.

Is there anyway I can change the source of the picture to the uploaded one before the page is submitted? Or can anyone thing of a clever way to do this?

Comment: Upload the image to a temp table that is used to store/display the thumbnail image. When the final image is saved to the database delete the row from the temp table.

Comment: @ObjectiveJ: Before the page is submitted?  Wouldn't you need the page to be submitted in order to upload the image?  It is coming from a user, right?

Comment: Its an ajax upload, so its does it without needing to submit the form, its mainly so all the information can be saved to the DB at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery or just plain javascript to modify the src attribute. You'll need to give the img tag an id attribute so you can distinguish it from the other img tag. This is very basic example that you will need to play around with to get it working:

```
// using jquery, assuming a button with the id "upload_button"
// is pressed when the image is selected
$('#upload_button').click(function() {
    $('img#my_img').attr('src', './path/to/new/image');
});
```

Comment: No idea, I was just giving him the option. Pure javascript like your answer provides is probably better.

Comment: I actually prefer the jquery answer, I just didn't know if it was available :)

Comment: My 'ajax' upload is actually JQuery... using the ajax it has built into it.

Comment: My issue is, that onclick of the upload button, the image hasn't actually uploaded yet, it takes a few mins then populates a <td> with the filename, so onclick there is nothing to actually put in it for a few seconds... if that makes sense. I may not be understanding something totally.

Comment: ohhh i see, I had a similar problem and what I had to do was set up a recurring ajax call that polled the backend to see if there was a new image, and if there was, then update the image div

Comment: You can check with jQuery/ajax to see if the file exists. If not, display a loading image, otherwise display the uploaded image

Comment: To clarify, you would re-check every one or two seconds and each time you check, determine whether to display the loading button or the uploaded image. When the uploaded image is available, then stop rechecking.

Comment: I basically used the line from this where it repopulates the source tag, and put it in the jqury ajax code, so when it populates my <td> with the file name, it also switches the picture src. Thank you both :)

Answer (score 1):

Give the image an id, such as

`<img id = "my_image" src="../shop/<?php echo $prodinforow["ProdThumb"]; ?>`

then:

in the onclick of the upload button, put:

`<div onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src = '/path/to/image'" id="upload"></div>`